# How do i insert the current date and time to DATETIME data type column in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

How do i insert the value of `date('d-m-Y h:i:s')` in the clock column with DATETIME data type in MySQL table?

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
$date=date('d-m-Y h:i:s');

    $sql=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO time (clock)VALUES($date)");
```

i keep getting this error
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '11:22:03)' at line 1`

Comment: date fuction returns a formatted date string, please post insert code

Comment: php date has no sa as formatting parameter https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Comment: i have posted the insert code. sorry for that.

Comment: @nbk its actually `h:i:s a` a value is am or pm.

Comment: why not using `$date=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');` ? and use format to show in am/pm when you need it?

Comment: My sql wants its datetime data in only special formats, when you retrieve it, format as you like -

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die

Comment: Also see: [when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql). Better yet start using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: If you have errors, you should post them in your question. Don't let us guess.

Comment: What is the data type for the `clock` column?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the data type for the `clock` column is DATETIME.

Answer (score 2):

According to the MySQL documentation, [11.3.1 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), the `DATETIME` type only supports the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, which is equivalent to PHP formats.

- `Y-m-d h:i:s` for **12 hour** format.
- `Y-m-d H:i:s` for **24 hour** format.

Adding `PM` or `AM` will not work on MySQL.

Comment: i tried this `$date=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');` and this error came out `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '09:59:30)' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in your code:

- MySQL's DATETIME data type expects the inserted values to be of the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s` (or `Y-m-d H:i:s` in PHP).
- DATETIME values must be enclosed in (single) quotes. (This is the reason for your syntax error.)

Your code should be:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = $connection->query("INSERT INTO time (clock) VALUES ('{$date}')");
```

However - Even if the value of `$date` doesn't come from user input, and contains no special SQL characters, it creates "[code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)", which is having variables being interpolated in SQL queries. You should start now using *parameterized prepared statements*. Which would be:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO time (clock) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $date);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: wow, this works great. it solved the error, Thank you so much sir. By the way, what about other values? do i need to type like `'{$date}'` as well or its just for DATETIME column?

Comment: You could also use `'$date'` in this case. Using `{$variable}` can be considered "good practice". In some cases you need it. Eg.: `"Time: {$value}ms"` works fine. But `"Time: $valuems"` will raise an error: "*unknown variable '$valuems'*". So I tend to always use `{}`, just to be consequent and avoid bugs.